# IOS Sort NSDictionary with given array order

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a dictionary with objects and keys. I want to sort that dictionary using the keys

```
dict  = [name : abc, city: xyz, date :xys,  location: mnq ...]
```

for example i want to pass like

```
array =  [name, location, city, date]
```

i want to sort the dicionary like

```
dict = [name : abc, location: mnq, city: xyz,date: xys ...]
```

It should sort dicationay,as per my passing array values
 **not like alphabet or allkeys or allValues order**

Comment: DICTIONARIES DONT HAVE AN ORDER! They are unordered key-value pairs, they have no particular order and you should never care about their order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *newkey = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"name",@"location", @"city", @"date", nil];
    int index = 0;


    for (id key in dictionary) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", [newkey objectAtIndex:index], [dictionary objectForKey:[newkey objectAtIndex:index]]);


        index++;
    }
```

Comment: Great Thanks !!
MrWaqasAhmed

Comment: i found anotherway in swift

Answer (score 0):

u can't sort dictionary ... make 2D array with key - value pairs and sort them afterwards with .sort() function

Answer (score 0):

```
    var dict : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    dict.setObject("damu", forKey: "name")
    dict.setObject("bng", forKey: "city")
    dict.setObject("sakha", forKey: "office")
    dict.setObject("apple", forKey: "technology")

// Searching array
    keysArray = ["name","city","office","tech"]

// returning Touple
    var dictTouples = returnTouppleWithDictionary(dict, sortWithArray: keysArray)
    print("\n\n Soreted as keys: \(dictTouples.allKeys) Values \(dictTouples.allValues) ")

// Touple

    func returnTouppleWithDictionary(dict : NSDictionary, sortWithArray: NSArray) ->(allKeys:NSArray, allValues:               NSArray){
    var arrayKeys : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var arrayValues : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    for i in 0..<keysArray.count{
        var key : NSString = keysArray[i] as! String
        var name: NSString? =  dict.objectForKey(key) as! String;
        arrayKeys.addObject(key)
        arrayValues.addObject(name!)
    }
    return(arrayKeys,arrayValues)
```

}